# How do I insert my Hero-Widget-Page to a BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build an App with a Bottomnavigationbar, which has my Home Screen on the first tab and my Hero-Widget-Page on the other tab.
The Problem is, that I need the `context` variable inside my Hero widget, and by using the `List<Widget>` for my different BottomNavigationBar Pages I only can display simple widgets like `Text`.

```dart
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
    {

      int _selectedIndex = 0;
    static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
    static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      Text(  // on this place I want to add what is in the body now
        'Home',
        style: optionStyle,
      ),
      Text(
         'Devices',
         style: optionStyle,
      )
     ];
    
    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    }
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: color_1,
            title: Text("Device Manager"),
          ),
          body: Row( // here I want to insert _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex) instead of the Herowidget itself
            children: [
            Hero(
            tag: 'matrix1',
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MatrixPageOne())),
              child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                              Image(  image: new AssetImage('imgs/matrix1.png'),
                                      height: 100,
                                      width: 100,),
                              Text("Matrix Kitchen", style: mytextStyle,),
                    ]
                  )
                ),
              ),
            Hero(
            tag: 'matrix2',
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MatrixPageTwo())),
              child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                              Image(  image: new AssetImage('imgs/matrix2.png'),
                                      height: 100,
                                      width: 100,),
                              Text("PARTY ROOM", style: mytextStyle,),
                    ]
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ] // wrap children
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: color_1,
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            selectedItemColor: color_2,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.devices),
                  title: Text("Home")),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.devices),
                  title: Text("Devices"))
            ]
             
            )
        );
      } // Widget build
    } // class _MyHomePageState
    }
```

Like this the Hero widget will be displayed on both pages, so the bottomNavigationBar is not working.
I thank everyone who has an idea on doing this right, I've already been trying this for two days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
class _MyHomePageStateState extends State<MyHomePageState> {
    static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

    final _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
        HeroPageHome(),
        HeroPageDevices()
    ];

    int _selectedIndex = 0;

    void _onItemTapped(int index) {
        setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
        });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: color_1,
                title: Text("Device Manager"),
            ),
            body: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                backgroundColor: color_1,
                currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
                selectedItemColor: color_2,
                onTap: _onItemTapped,
                items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.devices),
                        title: Text("Home")
                    ),
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.devices),
                        title: Text("Devices")
                    )
                ]

            )
        );
    }
}
```

Note that I created separate classes for your `Hero` pages.

```
class HeroPageHome extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Hero(
            tag: 'matrix1',
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MatrixPageOne())),
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        Image(  image: new AssetImage('imgs/matrix1.png'),
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                        ),
                        Text("Matrix Kitchen", style: mytextStyle,),
                    ]
                )
            ),
        );
    }
}

class HeroPageDevices extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Hero(
            tag: 'matrix2',
            child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MatrixPageTwo())),
                child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                        Image(  image: new AssetImage('imgs/matrix2.png'),
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,

                        ),
                        Text("PARTY ROOM", style: mytextStyle,),
                    ]
                )
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome @spawn.World1, you're most welcome ... be sure to accept this answer by clicking on the tick icon as it solved your problem

Comment: Ah yea ok i did now, didnt saw it before :D